# Having different info on each side

Tags: mysql

the problem i have with my query, is that i cant have both names be different to each others side

like if john logged in shows jane deo

if jane deo logged in shows john deo

```
TABLE USERS

+-----------------------------------+
|    id   |   name      |  country  |    
+-----------------------------------+
|    1    |   john deo  |  india    |
------------------------|-----------+
     2    |   jane deo  |  canada   |
+-----------------------------------+

TABLE POSTS

+-----------------------------------------+
|    id   |   post_from |     post_to     |    
+-----------------------------------------+
|    1    |    id 2     |     id 1        |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

John Account

show i sent post to jane deo. show name id country

Jane Account

show i got post from John deo. show name id country

logged in as john deo

```
select snd.id, snd.name, snd.country 
from posts as m
  JOIN users as snd ON snd.id = m.id 
where (m.post_from = 1 OR m.post_to = 1) # id 1 is john from users
```

logged in as jane deo

```
select snd.id, snd.name, snd.country 
from posts as m
    JOIN users as snd ON snd.id = m.id 
where (m.post_from = 2 OR m.post_to = 2) # id 2 is jane from users
```

Comment: Do you have a `SELECT` in front of that query with a JOIN? Because if you do please show it so it looks like a sensible complete query

Comment: yes updated question

Comment: you have to join user 2 times and then you use the post_to  id and post_from id to join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join the table USERS **twice** for every recipient or Sender one

> ```
> CREATE TABLE USERS (
>   `id` INT(5),
>   `name` VARCHAR(8),
>   `country` VARCHAR(20)
> );
> INSERT INTO USERS
>   (`id`, `name`, `country`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'john deo', 'india'),
>   (2,'jane deo', 'canada');
>
> CREATE TABLE POSTS (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `post_from` INTEGER,
>   `post_to` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO POSTS
>   (`id`, `post_from`, `post_to`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2', '1');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT u1. `id`,u1.`name`, u1.`country`,u2.`id`,u2.`name`, u2.`country`
> FROM POSTS p 
> INNER JOIN USERS u1 ON p.post_from = u1.id
> INNER JOIN USERS u2 ON p.post_to = u2.id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name     | country | id | name     | country
> -: | :------- | :------ | -: | :------- | :------
>  2 | jane deo | canada  |  1 | john deo | india
> ```

> ```
> select snd.id, snd.name, snd.country 
> from POSTS as m 
> JOIN USERS as snd ON snd.id = m.post_from 
> JOIN USERS as snd1 ON snd1.id = m.post_to
> where (m.post_to = '1' OR m.post_from = '2')
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name     | country
> -: | :------- | :------
>  2 | jane deo | canada
> ```

> ```
> select snd.id, snd.name, snd.country 
> from POSTS as m 
> JOIN USERS as snd ON snd.id = m.id 
> JOIN USERS as snd1 ON snd1.id = m.id2
> where (m.id = '1' OR m.id2 = '2')
> ```
>
> ```
> Unknown column 'm.id2' in 'where clause'
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b49eb1130ca7714a6bc3199f639fb11e)*

Comment: this did not work, but thanks for idea, i think using two joins will sort my problem, and if you can help me fix my query coz its syntax error. using join when i can include my ids myself from my code    (select  snd.id, snd.name, snd.country from
  posts as m
  JOIN users as snd ON snd.id = m.id where (m.id = '1' OR JOIN users as snd ON snd.id = m.id2 where m.id2 = '2')

Comment: your query makes no sense, sorry to say  even when you join snd2 on the right play behunf the ON clause, you don't have a m.id2, at leqast not in your description you can check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4f6f8e654aafe7b0da361578b8d6c496

Comment: as shown in my example you have to use the columnames to check the users